# MVC 3 override validation message css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to override the default validation css class for validators which is "field-validation-error" class

So, if I write a Validation message for a input on my form as below:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name)
```

Then the MVC runtime is setting the class of the message span by default as below:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name">
```

My question is, how can I remove the css class "field-validation-error" and replace it with another class (my version) which i will be using it in only some areas of my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok...so I got it working by setting the base "field-validation-error" class as "form .field-validation-error" in the root css file...which means that this class will have the highest priority  when the Html is generated and then in my View I included the new css class as mentioned below:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name, new { @class ="NewCssClass"})
```

This will generate the below markup:

```
<span class="field-validation-error NewCssClass" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name">
```

As you can see the NewCssClass will override the default validation style specified in the "field-validation-error" class...

Cheers...

Comment: are we missing the second param there? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, you're right, I didn't read that far through the MVC source - just read the extension method source.  Turns out [those fields are `static readonly`](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#266468) with no options to change.

So, you're stuck with one of two choices:

1. Deal with using the set class names.
2. Write your own extension methods (or easier, [just copy them](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#288016) from the MVC source and rename them).

Comment: thanks for the reply, the thing is HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName is a readonly field and cannot be set from your view???...

Comment: Read more source and fixed my answer.  Less than ideal though.

Comment: I like option C: don't use MVC validation!