# HtmlHelper class in System.Web.Webpages.Html vs System.Web.Mvc namespaces

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

In ASP.NET MVC3 I'm trying to set the css class that the validation error helper method sets. (Not [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733857/mvc-3-override-validation-message-css), the accepted answer just ADDS the class, I want to override it completely.) In looking at the MVC3 source I've found the `ValidationInputCssClassName` property on the HtmlHelper class. It is settable and it stores the value in a storage provider if set. The get method for the property returns [the provider value] `??` [the default class name].

Now if you just type in `HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName` ([MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.validationinputcssclassname.aspx)) in your controller code you'll see that it is a static readonly field. The reason for this is that there are two HtmlHelper classes, one is in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace, and the other is in the `System.Web.Webpages.Html` namespace. The property `System.Web.Webpages.Html.HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName` ([MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.validationinputcssclassname%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)) can be set, but it doesn't seem to have any effect the generated code no matter where I set it.

What am I missing? And what is the difference between these classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive but I think `System.Web.WebPages.Html` is for using ASP.net WebForms with Razor.

Since `ValidationInputCssClassName`, etc. are all readonly fields, I think the only way you are going to get around this is by creating your own HtmlHelper extension methods so you can customize this behavior.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.aspx):

> The System.Web.WebPages namespace contains core classes that are used
>   to render and execute pages that are built using ASP.NET Web Pages
>   with the Razor syntax.

Comment: I'm using Razor. The HtmlHelper property in the Web.WebPages namespace is clearly intended to be modified by something. Roll-your-own is a last resort, I don't wanna be porting updates with each MVC release!

Comment: @Paul I'm talking about WebForms with Razor. It's just a guess but that's what it sounds like it is supposed to be used for. ASP.net WebForms Razor pages.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the namespace description, it appears that one of them is designed for Razor and is intended to be used with WebMatrix.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549171(v=vs.99).aspx

Also:

The System.Web.Mvc namespace contains classes that are used to create HTML elements.

The types in this namespace are in the System.Web.WebPages assembly and are identical to the equivalent types in the System.Web.Mvc assembly.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc(v=vs.99).aspx